# ETL Job in AWS Glue for Historical Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a client who sends us data each month. However, each month's file contains all of their historical data as well as the new data from the current month. For example, in November 2020, the client sent us data from September 2018 - November 2020 inclusive. The file they will send in December 2020 will include data from September 2018 - December 2020 inclusive.

I want to perform an ETL job in Glue for only the *new* data (i.e. the data from the current month) each month. For example, I would like to extract just the December 2020 data from a CSV file that contains data from September 2018-December 2020. I have tried the following approaches to no avail:

1. Making use of job bookmarking: When enabled, the job will "ignore" data files that it has previously processed but still performs the ETL task on the entire new data file each month.
2. Making use of the SplitRows Class: While this can accomplish what I am looking for, it would require that I create a separate job for each month and year since the comparison-dict would have to be tailored to the month of interest. If possible, I would like to avoid having to do this.

While I am looking for solutions using AWS Glue, if none exist, I am open to making use of other AWS services (e.g. AWS DataPipeline) if necessary.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Bookmarks will not work because, a job bookmark for s3 looks at the timestamp of the file. If understand your usecase well, you are having data that is inclusive of previous months in a single file. Maybe you can use a filter to only write data that matches the months you have not processed. No tool is going to give you this answer without some transformation. You have to write this programmatically. Data pipeline is just the resources which require a shell command or a program to do the work you want. Another way is to read source and target and perform an outer join as a data frame.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I had a feeling that this would be the only option but I just wanted to double check.